# New to REST API and P12 certificates in Python and Requests

Tags: api, python-requests, pyopenssl, python-cryptography, p12

I was hoping to get some help in making a API Get request using the requests library via Python as I want to automate some API test scripts. I have access to the requests library but was wondering what is the proper syntax to authenticate a .p12 certificate in the requests session. After a few hours of Googleing I was going down a worm hole and was wondering if someone here can provide some guidance?

From my google searches I came across this website (https://blog.cyberreboot.org/using-pkcs-12-formatted-certificates-in-python-fd98362f90ba) but the line "from requests_toolbelt.adapters.x509 import X509Adapter" I'm getting an error because I don't have access to OpenSSL module. What is the alternative?

Comment: try to `pip install pyopenssl`

Comment: thanks a lot @dh762